# Java Application Crashes After Playing Sounds

Tags: java, swing, memory, audio

I'm trying to make a game with bunch of sound effects added. 
A lot of different sound effects will be played during the gameplay and I wasn't sure how to 
play sounds in java so I just used the code example from the link below:

http://www.anyexample.com/programming/java/java_play_wav_sound_file.xml

However, the following error keeps coming up and crashes the application about couple minutes after. 
(sometimes in few seconds, sometimes in few minutes)

```
Invalid memory access of location 0x54008 rip=0x11c7737fd
```

I'm simply making a new AePlayWave object and starting it whenever it needs to be played. 
like this:

```
new AePlayWave("Effect.wav").start();
```

Everything is perfect except for the program randomly crashing because of this. 
How could I solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a low-level access problem.  Maybe your audio driver has a bug in the way Java is trying to access it?

Comment: Yeah, it seems like a bug too but I don't know what I should do then :( Is there another simple way to play audio files like this one that you would suggest?

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have enough experience playing audio files (from Java or otherwise).  Btw, can you try this on another computer -- preferably one that has a different sound card/audio driver?

Comment: Yeah I should try this on another computer. I can't do it right now but I will later tonight. I should probably try another way to play the sound..

Comment: OK so before trying my program on another computer, I decided to just try it on Windows on my computer first (I'm using a macbook btw) using Parallels, and it runs perfectly fine on windows! So I guess it's not even the sound card. After some searching, it looks like there have already been some problems reported for handling audio on mac.. I'm not sure what I should do...

Comment: I can see two possibilities: 1) switch to Windows :); 2) search for a working sound library/driver and use JNI to interface with it

Comment: Well.. I can't switch to Windows first of all as this is the only computer that I have right now :( and I'm not really sure where to find the working sound library/driver and use JNI to interface with it? (I get that it's a Java Native Interface, but I'm not really sure where to go from there) I'm quite new to java and I have never worked with these kinds of things so please pardon my ignorance...

Comment: I was just joking about switching to Windows :)  Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with mac, so I don't think I will be of much help from heare on out.  I also did not work with JNI much, so all I can offer for you is to read some documentation/tutorials -- your favorite search engine should be able to provide you a lot of hits.  But first find a _working_ sound library for mac

Comment: Alright. I'll try to do my best to find the working sound library for mac but I'm already not doing so good :'( I can't believe there is no easy way to audio files on mac right now. I just need to play a really short wav file...